# Customising Zurb Foundation 5 Grid, Gutter and Max width

Tags: frameworks, grid, zurb-foundation

I've only been able to find one or two references to the maximum allowed column we can add to a customized version of Foundation5 and these claim the number is 16. However I can find no official documentation of this.

In the Foundation 5 download customizer there are input fields for '# of Columns', 'Gutter (em)', and 'Max-Width (em)'.
I have tested with a value of up to 24 columns and the CSS output has classes included for up to 24 columns, so I'd assume the 16 column restriction no longer applies (or only applies to older versions of Foundation).

So my questions are:

1. Does anyone know what the max number of columns allowed is / or if others are using a particular number successfully?
2. If I custom download Foundation5 with more columns, how do I know what gutter width and Max-Width values will work out correctly or can I just use anything (the downloader doesn't give any indication of incorrect values or out of range values)?
3. Having a custom download, how would I best manage Foundation updates if I wanted to upgrade the CSS to future newer versions?

PS: Im not using SASS or other pre-processor tools.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that the only way I can see doing this easily is by using Sass.
If you look on the grid docs page you can adjust the _setting.scss thus:

```
$row-width: rem-calc(1000);
$column-gutter: rem-calc(30);
$total-columns: 12 ;
```

[Foundation Grid docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html)

When you say upgrade the CSS to future newer versions do you mean newer versions of Foundation? If you did a customised version download then you would probably need to do it again. If you are also do other styling changes on your site outside of the Foundation stuff and you are not going to use Sass, I think your best option would be to keep them on a separate stylesheet.

Without sounding like a Sass evangelist...it is really worth your while to use it. Makes life so much easier!

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS customizer that lets you choose up to 100 columns http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/download.html

Also you can change it in Sass to any number.